# Can a Fabric command be given as a list of args?

Tags: fabric

I'd like to specify a remote command in Fabric in the form

```
['mkdir', '-p', path]
```

where `path` is the path to some directory I want to create.

Most people seem to be doing things like this:

```
run('mkdir -p {}').format(path)
```

But that doesn't work in the general case where `path` may contain spaces, quotes, and any other character that will mess with the shell parsing.

Is there a reliable way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the easiest solution for me was something like this:

- print directory name to the file,
- upload that file to the remote host
- execute shell command/script to load line from the file